# Search by Categories is not giving accurate result. how to solve?

Tags: magento-1.9, category, search

I have a problem with our search on front page of our website. It is not showing the correct result.

**For ex:** I search Reebok Shoes, it searched lot of thing related and unrelated, but didn't find the product I was expecting.

I made sure all the words are existing.

1. All products are enables.
2. Re-indexing is done.
3. All Categories is Is Anchor->'yes'.
4. Search type is Combine(Like and Fulltext).

What is this issue and can it be fixed. Can I need to make a module for search by categories?

What i found is:

1. I find that i need to add some code in Mage -> CatalogSearch -> Layer
2. I didn't get in which function i need to add, someone help please.
3. I need to add in prepareproductcollection. The code is not calling the category box.

I am looking for a code which can call category name from select option.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my previous experience searching would be affected by tags/meta tags, whether products should have selected with search or catalog,search option. Your product short/long description also matter. Indexing, caching need to perform when added new products or update previous.

You can use [Klevu](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/search-smartest-instant-search.html) or [Instant search](https://marketplace.magento.com/instantsearch-autocompleteplus-autosuggest.html). Both are free and have good rating.

Comment: all this is paid extension, i need free one. Can you suggest something free? my question is how can i linked categories and searching text(by user) and give result by this. Presently, when i choose reebox 10 size shoes, search gives result of adidas shoes and some other brand shoes, i need reebok shoes only